# Python: Appending to a list, which is value of a dictionary

Tags: python

Here is the code, which I would like to understand. I am creating a dict using elements of a list as keys and another list as default values. Then update this dict with another one. Finally, I would like to append to the list within dict. The append is happening multiple times for some of the elements. I would like append to happy only once for each of the values of dict.

```
l=['a','b','c']
bm=dict.fromkeys(l,['-1','-1'])
u={'a':['Q','P']}
bm.update(u)
bm
# {'a': ['Q', 'P'], 'c': ['-1', '-1'], 'b': ['-1', '-1']}
for k in bm.keys():
    bm[k].append('DDD')
bm
# {'a': ['Q', 'P', 'DDD'], 'c': ['-1', '-1', 'DDD', 'DDD'], 'b': ['-1', '-1', 'DDD', 'DDD']}
```

I was expecting appending `DDD` to happen once for `c` and `b` like this:

```
{'a': ['Q', 'P', 'DDD'], 'c': ['-1', '-1', 'DDD'], 'b': ['-1', '-1', 'DDD']}
```

Answer (score 1):

this

```
bm=dict.fromkeys(l,['-1','-1'])
```

Is reusing the same list `['-1','-1']` for all keys, which explains the effect you're witnessing.

to achieve what you want you could do this with a *dict comprehension*

```
bm = {x:[-1,1] for x in ['a','b','c']}
```

(the loop within the dict comp ensures that a different instance of the `[-1,1]` list is created for each value, which guarantees independence)

Full example:

```
bm = {x:[-1,1] for x in ['a','b','c']}

u={'a':['Q','P']}
bm.update(u)
print(bm)
for k in bm.keys():
    bm[k].append('DDD')

print(bm)
```

result:

```
{'c': [-1, 1], 'a': ['Q', 'P'], 'b': [-1, 1]}
{'c': [-1, 1, 'DDD'], 'a': ['Q', 'P', 'DDD'], 'b': [-1, 1, 'DDD']}
```

Note: if you want that all accessed keys create a default value when not present you can use `defaultdict` with a lambda which creates a different instance of `['-1','-1']` every time.

```
from collections import defaultdict
bm = defaultdict(lambda : ['-1','-1'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Jean-François Fabre for clarification. Using dict comprehension I could get what I wanted.